# How to run the simplest unit test

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I just want to run a unit test, but I must be missing something from the documentation.   From what I read, just running this file with "ruby" should execute my test, however nothing happens.  What must I be missing?!

```
class PracticeTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def simple_test
    puts "in here"
    assert_equal(1, 2)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

ohh the name of the method has to start with "test_"